# Highcharts - Multiple Charts On Mobile Page

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with HighCharts. I am building a mobile page that will contain upwards of 20 charts on the screen however there is a large delay (5 - 10 seconds) for the charts to render. I am using DotNet.Highcharts to construct the charts on the server side and then just rendering the div and script tags that creates to the page.

My question is: has anyone attempted something similar (I'm sure i cant be the only one) and how did you get past this so your users don't experience the 'lag' of rendering those charts?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

When I first started developing a dashboard for my company I was told that I MUST support IE8, as most of our clients would be using it.

I too had to render close to 20 charts on the fly...and boy did my load time suffer, in fact...it ranged between 30 seconds and 2 minutes.

What I did to combat this is actually separate the charts. Instead of having all 20 or so on one page, I separated them out into "tabs" or different sections of the page, and I only initialized the charts when they needed to be shown. Instead of one large delay, there were several very small delays.

I'm not sure if this is something you could accomplish on your site without seeing it, but it may be worth a try!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this might prove to be cumbersome for the user as the data is already paged and there could potentially be upwards of 70 individual items, each item having 2 charts, and that's a lot of paging for the user. I will investigate this and see if perhaps i can implement something similar.

Comment: No problem, sorry I don't have a better solution. Some browsers just aren't "up to par" with the power required by Highcharts to render graphs. Chome cuts through them like butter...IE8 not so much, and I imagine some mobile phones/browsers will have trouble too.

Comment: Also, usability is obviously a big concern, try asking yourself if all of the graphs are useful immediately. Are my users going to be looking at all 20 of these graphs? Can I show them other information that will lead them to one set of two graphs to investigate? For instance "Obj A - 37% +13% change | View Trending" Then have a list of those, and view trending would show the graphs.

Comment: Very good point. The issue is I am converting our existing reporting engine over to a mobile friendly version. Our desktop site has many more charts so this is the data the user is expecting, we have already trimmed it down, however the desktop site is currently rendering the charts using an old charting engine that renders the charts as gif so performance isn't an issue when rendering the charts.

Comment: If no interactivity, tooltips, etc are required, honestly pre-rendering them might be the best solution for mobile as well. Also, users have to understand that mobile is not always the best way to view data, and on mobile, the "best way" may be different than the desktop site. "Guess what, on mobile, my load times were ridiculous, so you get a smaller table with information, and then you can view the graphs, and this is easier to read." or "If you really want to see all of the graphs on mobile, speed is a concern, so we may have to use gifs still, this isn't as robust, but it will work."

Comment: You raise very valid points I will have to bring these up with the team. Thanks for the suggestions, i will update once i find the 'preferred' solution.