# HighChart (HighStock) - how do I reduce the chance of a slow-script warning in IE8

Tags: highcharts

We're creating some rather complicated multi-graph charts and on IE8 we sporadically get the dreaded slow-script warning.  Without asking our customers to do anything to the registry, what can we do to prevent this?  Is there--for example--a setting somewhere to ask HighCharts to call setTimeout occasionally?  Do we have to break up our graph generation manually?

Comment: Did you turn off chart animation?

Comment: Disabe all markers, animations and shadows. Not sure what do you need to do with setTimeout, could you explain a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite tell if you mean single charts with multiple graphs in them, or if you have multiple graphs on the page, but see my discussion here:

[Highcharts - Multiple Charts On Mobile Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341107/highcharts-multiple-charts-on-mobile-page/15341454#15341454)

Sometimes it's better to just break everything up.

Also, while your customers can't do anything to the registry, they can install Google Chrome Frame, we advise that to all of our clients. They don't need admin privileges to install, it won't break any of their "legacy" software or anything. It merely turns lower versions of IE into Chrome only on pages that tell it to do so.